# Sbt/Scala - Gitlab dependency

Tags: scala, gitlab, sbt

I'm trying to add in my build.sbt file a dependency to a private gitlab repository via SSH. I have found some documentation online to do this using github examples and I translated this to gitlab:

```
lazy val libOnGitlab = ProjectRef(uri("git@gitlab.com:username/myproject.git"), "RandomNameHere")
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(libOnGitlab).settings(libraryDependencies += ...)
```

The problem I have is that Gitlab's SSH link is using a **@** while github doesn't and this gives me an error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 3: git@gitlab.com:...
```

I have already tried many many different things (prepending it with some protocol etc) but I'm pretty new to this and can't manage to solve it. Any ideas?